# Erros com manipulação de array em C

Tags: c, array

Através do seguinte código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
//Declaração de Variáveis
char jogo;
char times[20][15] = {"Corinthians","Atlético-MG","Grêmio","Santos","São Paulo","Internacional","Sport","Palmeiras","Ponte Preta","Flamengo",
"Cruzeiro","Atlético-PR","Fluminense","Chapecoense","Figueirense","Havaí","Coritiba","Goias","Joinville","Vasco da Gama"};
int pontos[20] = {70,62,56,50,50,50,49,48,47,44,44,42,40,39,35,34,33,31,30,30};
int menu=0, opcao, realpos=0, i=0;
//Entrada de dados
while ((menu > 0) && (menu<3)) {
  switch (menu) {
    case 1: escreva("+----BRASILEIRAO 2015---+");
      for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
      printf("%d + - %d", i+1, times[i], pontos[i]);
      }
      printf("+----FIM---+");
      menu = 666;
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("Digite o a posição do time que deseja simular");
      scanf("%d", &opcao);

      for (i=1; i<=8;i++){
        realpos = opcao-1;
        printf("Digite o resultado do %dº jogo do %s. (vitoria, empate ou derrota)", i, times[realpos]);
        scanf(%c, &jogo);
        switch (jogo) {
          case "vitoria":
            pontos[realpos] = pontos[realpos] + 3;
            break;
          case "empate":
            pontos[realpos] = pontos[realpos] + 1;
            break;
          case "derrota":
            pontos[realpos] = pontos[realpos];
            break;
          default:
            printf("Digite o resultado do %dº jogo do %s. (vitoria, empate ou derrota)", i, time[realpos]);
            scanf(%d, &jogo);
            break;
        }
      }

      for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
      printf("%d -  %s  -  %d", (i+1), times[i], pontos[i]);
      }
      break;
  }
  printf("Digite 0 para sair");
  scanf("%d", &opcao);
  }
```

temos os seguintes erros ao compilar:

```
    tabelaBrasileirao.c: In function ‘main’:
tabelaBrasileirao.c:15:7: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
       printf("%d + - %d", i+1, times[i], pontos[i]);
       ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:15:7: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
tabelaBrasileirao.c:27:9: error: expected expression before ‘%’ token
   scanf(%c, &jogo);
         ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:29:11: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
           case "vitoria":
           ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:32:11: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
           case "empate":
           ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:35:11: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
           case "derrota":
           ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:39:94: error: ‘time’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             printf("Digite o resultado do %dº jogo do %s. (vitoria, empate ou derrota)", i, time[realpos]);
                                                                                              ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:39:94: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
tabelaBrasileirao.c:40:10: error: expected expression before ‘%’ token
    scanf(%d, &jogo);
          ^
tabelaBrasileirao.c:52:3: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
   }
   ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não conseguir olhar os erros e achar problemas simples assim, não vai conseguir programar. Está faltando você se dedicar um pouco para tentar achar os erros, alguns são erros de digitação, e muitos deles acontecem porque o código não está organizado.

Talvez o único erro que seja por falta de conhecimento é o uso de *string* em um `case`. Não pode. Dá para fazer algo mais complexo, mas preferi simplificar.

Decidi resolver só os erros de compilação. Agora você pode testar e ver se está fazendo o que deseja. Depois, se tiver dúvidas, faça uma nova pergunta com o problema específico, dizendo o problema em detalhes e tudo o que tentou.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 
int main() {
    char times[20][15] = {"Corinthians", "Atlético-MG", "Grêmio", "Santos", "São Paulo", "Internacional", "Sport", "Palmeiras", "Ponte Preta", "Flamengo",
    "Cruzeiro", "Atlético-PR", "Fluminense", "Chapecoense", "Figueirense", "Havaí", "Coritiba", "Goias", "Joinville" ,"Vasco da Gama"};
    int pontos[20] = {70, 62, 56, 50, 50, 50, 49, 48, 47, 44, 44, 42, 40, 39, 35, 34, 33, 31, 30, 30};
    int menu = 0;
    //Entrada de dados
    while (menu > 0 && menu < 3) {
        int opcao, realpos = 0;
        switch (menu) {
        case 1: printf("+----BRASILEIRAO 2015---+");
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) printf("%d -  %s - %d", i + 1, times[i], pontos[i]);
            printf("+----FIM---+");
            menu = 666;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Digite o a posição do time que deseja simular");
            scanf("%d", &opcao);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
                realpos = opcao - 1;
                printf("Digite o resultado do %dº jogo do %s. (V, E ou D)", i, times[realpos]);
                char jogo;
                scanf("%c", &jogo);
                switch (jogo) {
                    case 'V':
                        pontos[realpos] += 3;
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        pontos[realpos]++;
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("Digite o resultado do %dº jogo do %s. V, E ou D)", i, times[realpos]);
                        scanf("%c", &jogo);
                        break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) printf("%d -  %s  -  %d", (i+1), times[i], pontos[i]);
            break;
        }
        printf("Digite 0 para sair");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RqzhWn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mphsxaeb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Brasileirao.c).

Answer (score 1):

**1°** - Você esta declarando a variavel `jogo` como char e utilizando como string.

**2°** - Você não pode usar instrução switch com strings.

**3°** - Na linha 27 deve estar assim: scanf("%c", &jogo);

**4°** - Cade a função escreva ?

**5°** - Na linha 39 `times` esta escrito errado.

**Dicas:**

Aconselho utilizar o `do{}while();` para chamar o menu pelo menos uma vez e caso a condição prevaleca verdadeira
continue a chamar o menu.

Divida  seu código em pequenos pedaços para facilitar o entendimento/manutenção, você pode dividir seu código em:

`do{}while()` > chama a função `menu()`.

Usuário escolhe a opção no `menu()` direciona para a função `resultadoJogo()`,

Usuário digita o resultado, `resultadoJogo()` direciona de volta para o `menu()`.