# Como incrementar um enum em C?

Tags: c, enums

De forma objetiva como eu faço para incrementar `++` ou `+= 1` uma das variáveis do `enum` (o incremento vai estar em um *loop* / `switch`):

```
enum {um = 0, dois = 0 ... seis = 0};
```

Eu li essa [pergunta](http://computer-programming-forum.com/47-c-language/ed612d8145a3ba9f.htm) e não entendi bem. Alguma dica de estrutura melhor para guardar os dados (que são seis *strings* seus respectivos valores)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem segredo e é o que aquele código mostra. Cria-se a enumeração. Declara uma variável do tipo da enumeração, atribui-se um dos valores possíveis para a variáveis, e já pode usar uma constante da enumeração, ainda que possa ser qualquer valor, não há verificação de uso, e depois faz o incremento. A variável será um inteiro normal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {um = 1, dois = 2, tres = 3} Numeros;

int main(void) {
    Numeros numero = um;
    numero++;
    printf("%d", numero);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/eSLeTw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cxvvwtnu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/EnumIncrement.c).

Esta é a pergunta que fez e está respondida. Mas a descrição também indica que não deseja isso. A primeira coisa que precisa definir é se precisa de *string* mesmo, ou só precisa de um conjunto de variáveis que guardam alguns valores e que esses valores é que devem ser incrementados, aí é só usar um *array* de `int` bem simples, que é um recurso bem mais básico de C. e como já programou em C antes deve saber fazer.

[Há uma pergunta que mostra o uso prático disto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97313/101).

Comment: Nesse caso o nome é necessário, vlw.